# Rails integration testing: Should we use strings or named routes in http requests?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

When integration testing Rails applications [HTTP request helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#helpers-available-for-integration-tests) can take a string or a named route as the first argument.

I find myself writing:

```
test "user visits edit page" do
  homer = users(:homer)
  get "users/#{homer.id}/edit"
  assert_response :success
end
```

But I can also write:

```
test "user visits edit page" do
  homer = users(:homer)
  get edit_user_path(homer)
  assert_response :success
end
```

So which style should I use? And why is it preferable to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 2nd version - i.e. use the path helper methods, don't use strings. Or use a 3rd one, detailed below.

Ideally, you [test your routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#testing-routes) separately from the controller (in `test/routes/`/`spec/routes/` files). That'll test that `"/users/homer/edit"` indeed routes to the `users#edit` action. Provided your using Rails' standard resourceful routes, you don't need further tests. Anything more would be you testing that *Rails* works, which should be unnecessary. You want to test *your* app.

Secondly, the reason Rails provides path/url helper methods is that hard-coding paths/urls is a recipe for a headache should the representation of those paths ever change. For instance, a simple `resources :users, as: :people` in the routes file would break all your hard-coded "/users/..." paths.

Thirdly, you're simply writing `homer.id`. But path helpers call `to_param` (which you can override in your models) on the object they're passed. So you're not accurately mimicking the way the path helper methods work.

Basically, if you make a change in `routes.rb`, you don't want to have to update your controller tests - after all, you didn't necessarily change your controllers! You only want to update your routing tests, if you have any.

Alternatively, (edit: this is for *controller* tests, specifically) you can use a *third* version, where you specify action and params separately:

```
get :edit, { id: homer.to_param }
```

This way, you side-step both hard-coded URLs, route matching, *and* path/URL helpers entirely. This is probably the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: Thanks! But in the third scenario, how would the test know the right controller? If it can be inferred from the user, what about `:new` where no user object is used? If it's from the name of the test, I found that their names aren't not usually anologous to controllers.

Comment: @Mohamad Right, sorry - I was thinking controller tests (where the controller is derived from the test class/spec name), rather than high-level integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `resources :users, as: :people` will still break helpers too (`users_path` becomes `people_path`), it's much easier to find & replace helper methods, than hard-coded strings.